# Django sorted list in Class-Based-Views

Tags: python, django

I want to return a sorted list, when request method = GET, the given query string (if its not null) is provided by a search box. Can i do it in this CBV or i have to define a new view just for this job?

My views.py :

```
class DolgozokListView(ListView):

model = Dolgozo

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(DolgozokListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    return context

def get(self, request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search_box', None)
    if (search_query is not None):
        context = super(DolgozokListView, self).object_list.filter(nev__conatains = search_query)
    else:
        context = super(DolgozokListView, self).get_context_data

    return context
```

but i got the following error:

```
Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:50033/dolgozo/

Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.11
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'app',
'DolgozoKarbantart',
'DolgozoMunkakorKarbantart',
'FelhasznaloKarbantart',
'MunkaIdoAdatKarbantart',
'MunkakorKarbantart')
 Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')

Traceback:

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in                    get_response  235.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in           process_response
 112.         if response.status_code == 404:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dolgozo/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

Comment: The `get` method must return a response, I'm not sure if you're trying to define `get_context_data` method or you need to return the correct response object.

Comment: i want to return a sorted 'Dolgozo' list, filtered  by search_query

Comment: But as Sayse says, any view, whether it's class-based or not, needs to return a response - that is, a subclass of HttpResponse.

Comment: Thanks for the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = self.model.objects.all()
    search = self.request.GET.get('search_box', None)
    if search:
        qs=qs.filter(nev__icontains=search)

    return qs
```

Comment: That's correct, but i would suggest using qs = super(DolgozokListView, self).get_queryset() instead of qs = self.model.objects.all().

Comment: What is the meaning of the first one that you said?

Comment: I think that you should use method of superclass ListView to get queryset like 'qs = super(DolgozokListView, self).get_queryset()'